# How to do ESM dynamic export?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

The following exports code used to work when I set the project as CommonJS

```js
let group: keyof typeof cloudFunctions;
// loop through all groups built above and export them
for (group in cloudFunctions) {
  if (group != null) {
    exports[group] = cloudFunctions[group];
  }
}
```

Now, I am trying to convert this to ESM Module so I use ESM `export`, instead of CJS `exports` but it keeps throwing me error.

```js
let group: keyof typeof cloudFunctions;
// loop through all groups built above and export them
for (group in cloudFunctions) {
  if (group != null) {
    export[group] = cloudFunctions[group];
  }
}
```

The only way I can workaround it is to declare this statically and manually one by one OUTSIDE the for loop at the top-level.

Question: How can I adopt the similar structure I had in CJS in ESM so that I can programmatically export the functions stored inside a variable?

Comment: Just a tangential note: `if (group != null) {/*...*/}` will always evaluate to `true` because `null`/`undefined` can't be keys of objects (so you can just skip that check in your code).

Comment: What is `cloudFunctions`? And why are you copying its values instead of using the object itself?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do dynamic export with ESM. ESM requires exports to be statically analyzable.

Instead, you can export an object that you define dynamically:

```
export const someName = {...cloudFunctions};
```

...or perhaps just export `cloudFunctions` directly, since it appears to already have what you want to export:

```
export { cloudFunctions };
```

Code importing from the module will not be able to directly import properties from the object you export; instead, it will have to import the object and then use the desired property. For instance, if I assume you do direclty export `cloudFunctions`:

...then to import (say) the `whatever` function, then assuming you used `someName` as the name of the export:

```
import { someName } from "./the-module";
const { whatever } = someName;

// ...code using `whatever`...
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder! Even though your suggestion of `export const someName = {...cloudFunctions};` makes my code compiled, it throws another error when I run it. I know it may not align with the original subject of this question. Please see if you know there is a fix: 'Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension...`

Comment: @CupidChan - I'm afraid those are completely unfamiliar error messages, whatever tool is giving you those isn't one I've worked with.

Comment: Thanks again @T.J. Crowder! When I look at this close, I found out that even though I don't have any compile error using `export const someName = {...cloudFunctions};`, this may not be the expected "export" for the framework I am looking since it has "someName" for the whole thing, instead of exporting the content inside cloudFunctions one by one. Do you know the equivalent to translate directly from CJS to ESM export in the situation I described original sample code?

Comment: @CupidChan - If it's dynamic, you can't. ESM just doesn't do dynamic exports.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue. After some research I realized that ESM doesn't support dynamic export directly, i.e.

```
export initFunctionReturnsObject();
```

There are two options to provide dynamic interface, both require some extra code to import properly. Let's assume we have init.js with dynamic export object { a, b } generated by function initFunctionReturnsObject. Then we can

1. `export default initFunctionReturnsObject() // generate { a, b }`

   ```
   import init from './init.js';
   const { a, b } = init;
   ```

   another way is to use dynamic import

   ```
   const { default: { a, b } } = await import('./init.js');
   ```
2. `export const obj = initFunctionReturnsObject()`

   ```
   import { obj } from './init.js';
   const { a, b } = obj;
   ```

I hope this will help sort out how dynamic import might work in ESM

Comment: in my case, i have already populate all I need in a variable. With the "old" exports, it's just a matter of simple assignment. But I couldn't find an equivalence using the new export.